# roots of unity is a subgroup under multiplication

Tags: group-theory, roots-of-unity

this is my first stack exchange post, so forgive my lack of knowledge on formatting

I'm trying to prove that the $n$th roots of unity together with multiplication form a subgroup from $S^1$, where $S^1 = \{e^{i\theta}\;|\; \theta\in\mathbb{R}\}.$

I am stuck in trying to prove that the $n$th roots of unity are closed under multiplication.

If $n$th roots of unity $C_n = \{e^{k(2\pi i/n)}\; |\; k \in \{0,1, \dots, n-1\}\}$

Let $\;a=e^{j( 2\pi i/n)},\; b=e^{\ell(2\pi i/n)}\; |\; 0\leq j, \ell\leq n-1.$

Then $a b = e^{(j+\ell)2\pi i/n}.$
But there's no guarantee that $j+\ell \leq n-1$, so I cannot see how I can claim that $C_n$ is closed under multiplication.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Don't forget that $e^{2\pi i}=1$

Comment: [This may help with formatting.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have to show: if $x$ and $y$ are two roots of unity, then $xy$ is also a root of unity. Since, $x$ is a root of unity, there exists a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^n=1$. Similarly, there exists a $m  \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $y^m = 1$. Now, you have to find a $k$ such that $(xy)^k=1$. Do you know what that $k$ is?

Comment: Oh, using this definition is much clearer than the one I had included. Since $x$ and $y$ are both in $C_n$, would it be correct to say then that $x^n = y^n = 1$ and thus $(xy)^n=x^ny^n=1*1=1$?

Comment: Are you looking at nth roots of unity? Or all roots of unity?